# Android - IOIO board , simple UART code issue

Tags: android, accessory, ioio

I am using the IOIO board given by sparkfun. While trying to test UART , I tied the RX and TX of the IOIO board and wanted to send one byte from the phone and receive same byte on the Phone ans show it in a textbox. When I run the following code , nothing changes in the UI. I think I am missing a fundamental thing. Any suggestions / ideas ?

```
package ioio.examples.hello;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import ioio.examples.hello.R;
import ioio.lib.api.DigitalOutput;
import ioio.lib.api.IOIO;
import ioio.lib.api.IOIOFactory;
import ioio.lib.api.exception.ConnectionLostException;
import ioio.lib.api.exception.IncompatibilityException;
import ioio.lib.util.AbstractIOIOActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import ioio.lib.api.Uart;

/**
 * This is the main activity of the HelloIOIO example application.
 * 
 * It displays a toggle button on the screen, which enables control of the
 * on-board LED. This example shows a very simple usage of the IOIO, by using
 * the {@link AbstractIOIOActivity} class. For a more advanced use case, see the
 * HelloIOIOPower example.
 */

public class MainActivity extends AbstractIOIOActivity {

private ToggleButton togglebutton;
private TextView textView;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created. Here we normally initialize
 * our GUI.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    togglebutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
}

/**
 * This is the thread on which all the IOIO activity happens. It will be run
 * every time the application is resumed and aborted when it is paused. The
 * method setup() will be called right after a connection with the IOIO has
 * been established (which might happen several times!). Then, loop() will
 * be called repetitively until the IOIO gets disconnected.
 */
class IOIOThread extends AbstractIOIOActivity.IOIOThread {
    /** The on-board LED. */

    private Uart uart;
    private InputStream in;
    private OutputStream out;
    private byte receivedData[] = new byte[10];
    private int offset = 0;
    private Byte b;
    protected IOIO ioio_;

    /**
     * Called every time a connection with IOIO has been established.
     * Typically used to open pins.
     * 
     * @throws ConnectionLostException
     *             When IOIO connection is lost.
     * 
     * @see ioio.lib.util.AbstractIOIOActivity.IOIOThread#setup()
     */
    @Override
    protected void setup() throws ConnectionLostException {
        // led_ = ioio_.openDigitalOutput(0, true);
        ioio_ = IOIOFactory.create();
        try {
            ioio_.waitForConnect();
        } catch (IncompatibilityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        uart = ioio_.openUart(3, 4, 115200, Uart.Parity.NONE,
                Uart.StopBits.ONE);
        in = uart.getInputStream();
        out = uart.getOutputStream();
    }

    /**
     * Called repetitively while the IOIO is connected.
     * 
     * @throws ConnectionLostException
     *             When IOIO connection is lost.
     * 
     * 
     * @see ioio.lib.util.AbstractIOIOActivity.IOIOThread#loop()
     */
    @Override
    protected void loop() throws ConnectionLostException {

        offset = 0;
        while (togglebutton.isChecked()) {
        try {
                out.write(65);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Ignore
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO ???
            }
            try {
                in.read(receivedData, 0, 1);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Ignore
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO ???
            }

            textView.setText(Byte.toString(receivedData[0]));
        }
    }

}

/**
 * A method to create our IOIO thread.
 * 
 * @see ioio.lib.util.AbstractIOIOActivity#createIOIOThread()
 */
@Override
protected AbstractIOIOActivity.IOIOThread createIOIOThread() {
    return new IOIOThread();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

It seems that anything passed to the UI must occur in a separate thread. Your case you'd have to add something like this:

```
        private void changeText(String displayText){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setText(displayText);

            }   
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One obvious error you have is that:

```
ioio_ = IOIOFactory.create();
try {
    ioio_.waitForConnect();
} catch (IncompatibilityException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

is completely unnecessary and possibly problematic. AbstractIOIOActivity takes care of all that for you. Have a look at some of the examples (e.g. HelloIOIO or IOIOSimpleApp) to get an idea regarding what your app should typically look like.

By the way, the proper place for such questions is the ioio-users list on Google groups.